# removing special character encoding

Tags: php, regex, utf-8, htmlspecialchars

I have a string coming from an XML file that appears to have been encoded with `htmlspecialchars()` twice:

```
$data = "string&amp;#44;s example";
```

I've tried replacing `&amp;` with just an amphersand, then calling `htmlspecialchars_decode()`, and then replacing simple amphersands with the word "and", but the output comes out like `stringand#44; example`.
I'm wondering if there is a way to correctly convert these character encodings, or perhaps a regex to strip them out entirely (as i could simply strip them and use this as a value to check against later)?

Comment: It's encoded twice, which seems unusual. Did you get that from the plain text, or is it the XML-encoding already parsed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This particular string [needs to be processed twice](http://ideone.com/9ApgaY) by [`html_entity_decode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) to get its "real" value (the first of these calls can also be `htmlspecialchars_decode`). The first pass will convert `&amp;` to `&` and the second will convert the entity `&#44;` to the corresponding character.

You should be careful to pass in all relevant parameters to the decoding function calls (the defaults don't make sense in all cases) and of course be sure that all of the incoming data is encoded in this manner so that you don't get broken output by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Use [html_entity_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) as follows:

```
$data = html_entity_decode ( html_entity_decode ( $data ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Though it almost certainly works as intended in native PHP, the accepted solution appears to do nothing when applied to a string that is being fed from a Laravel controller to its view. For example, to dump a variable, I found that the only effective way to do so was to feed the value returned by e. g., `print_r ( $_ENV , true )` through a `with` method, and put the enclosing `pre` tags into the view.

**Controller:**

```
$sDebugMessages = '$_ENV = '.  print_r ( $_ENV , true ) ;
return view ( 'Info' )->with ( 'sPageTitle' , 'What is My Praesidium Central Hub?' )->with ( 'sDebugMessages' , $sDebugMessages ) ;
```

**View:**

```
pre>{{ $sDebugMessages }}</pre>
```

**Result (redacted, for reasons that should be ovvious:**

```
$_ENV = Array
(
    [APP_ENV] => local
    [APP_KEY] => xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    [APP_DEBUG] => true
    [APP_LOG_LEVEL] => debug
    [APP_URL] => https://localhost
    [DB_CONNECTION] => mysql
    [DB_HOST] => localhost:3306
    [DB_DATABASE] => xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    [DB_USERNAME] => xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    [DB_PASSWORD] => xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    [BROADCAST_DRIVER] => log
    [CACHE_DRIVER] => file
    [SESSION_DRIVER] => database
    [QUEUE_DRIVER] => sync
    [MAIL_DRIVER] => smtp
    [MAIL_HOST] => xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    [MAIL_PORT] => 587
    [MAIL_ENCRYPTION] => tls
    [MAIL_USERNAME] => xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    [MAIL_PASSWORD] => xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    [MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS] => xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    [MAIL_FROM_NAME] => xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    [MAIL_MODE] => xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    [MAIL_MODE_EMAIL] => xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
)
```